# Exportar grande quantidade de dados para Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-excel, datagridview

Tenho um `DataGridView` onde nele *há uma média de umas 50 mil linhas* onde essas deveriam ser exportadas para um arquivo Excel.

Porém pelo fato da enorme quantidade de dados a aplicação simplesmente congela e não finaliza, estou utilizando a biblioteca *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel*  o código do botão é esse:

```
 private void btnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //exportando arquivos para o excel
        if (dgvDados.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                for (int i = 1; i < dgvDados.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    XcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dgvDados.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvDados.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dgvDados.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvDados.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                //
                XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                //
                XcelApp.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro : " + ex.Message);
                XcelApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Há alguma maneira de exportar algo desse nível para o excel?

Comment: Tenta criar paginações, ex: se são 50 mil linhas faz com que ele vá ao banco e busque a cada 10 mil, abrindo várias requisições dentro de cada paginação.

Comment: A aplicação está congelando porque está processando bastante coisa na Thread principal, se você criar uma nova thread para Executar isso a aplicação não vai congelar

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer dizer com "trava", ocorre algum erro, o processo não termina ou só demora e a interface do usuário congela até a finalização?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a interface congela, mas eu nunca vi ela finalizar e eu já deixei questão de 1h e ainda sim continua congelada

Comment: debugando, você mediu quanto tempo está demorando por linha, apesar do grande volume não tem tanta complexidade assim...

Comment: fiz o teste agora por linha acabou sendo muito variável, por exemplo quando abro a aplicação e exporto pela primeira vez demora cerca de *5s* mas depois de executado a primeira vez ele leva em torno de 0,5s. Testei com 7mil linhas e demorou 15 min

Comment: o problema mesmo é a aplicação ficar congelada sem poder fazer nada, acredito que thread seja realmente uma boa opção mas não conheço mt bem o recurso vou dar uma pesquisada

Comment: mas ainda sim se seguir por esse raciocínio 7 mil linhas = 15 min 50 mil linhas =~ 2h é muito tempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o clipboard para fazer a operação. Para essa quantidade de dados também vai demorar um pouco, porém vai ser bem mais rápido que copiar célula por célula

```
    private void btnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvDados.Rows.Count == 0) return;

        bool RowHeadersVisible = dgvDados.RowHeadersVisible;

        //Seleciona todas linhas de dgvDados e passa para o clipboard
        dgvDados.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dgvDados.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dgvDados.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null) Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);

        dgvDados.RowHeadersVisible = RowHeadersVisible;

        //Declara as variáveis para usar para referir aos elementos do excel 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        //Cria uma nova instanci do excel
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;

        //Adiciona um workbook
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        //Pega a primeira planilha do workbook
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Seleciona a primeira célula
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();

        //Cola o conteúdo do clipboard
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
    }
```

Comment: Pela quantidade de dados seria melhor usar [OleDb](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8), um [exemplo aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB).

Comment: que biblioteca eu devo chamar com o `using` para utilizar o namespace `Excel` ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia

Comment: muito bom, o que era quase um estimado de 3h agora faz em 45s melhora gritante, desde modo ele seleciona todas as linhas de uma só vez é muito mais eficiente

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu objetivo é não congelar a interface do usuário, você pode iniciar uma nova `Task`
para realizar essa tarefa, mas isso não vai resolver a questão do tempo para a execução.

```
private void btnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //exportando arquivos para o excel
    if (dgvDados.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {

                XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                for (int i = 1; i < dgvDados.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    XcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dgvDados.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvDados.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dgvDados.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvDados.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                //
                XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                //
                XcelApp.Visible = true;

                MessageBox.Show("Sucesso : Exportação concluída");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro : " + ex.Message);
                XcelApp.Quit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```